# How to get the output of a function handle after called afterEach in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I try to update the value of a variable once it receive a data, so that I could update the message on waitbar on how many jobs it has completed. My code looks something like this:

```
function value = completedJobs(value)
value=value+1;
end

job=0;
dq = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
wb = waitbar(0,'Processing');
afterEach(dq, @(varargin) completedJobs(job)) // this is where I would like to update the waitbar with new completed jobs on the message
afterEach(dq, @(varargin) waitbar(job,sprintf('Completed: %d', job));
parfor i=1:100
    send(dq, i);
end
```

And is it possible to merge twice calling of the `afterEach` into only one that could perform what those two calling did?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Make sure you move the completedJobs function to its own script otherwise the clear function on line 1 won't work.

```
clear completedJobs
dq = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
wb = waitbar(0,'Processing');
Listener = afterEach(dq, @(varargin) waitbar((completedJobs/100),wb,sprintf('Completed: %d', completedJobs(1))));
parfor i=1:100
    send(dq, i);
end
delete(wb);
```

Because the completedJobs function is called twice for every listened event you need to have a switch within the function to ensure that n is only incremented once. This is done by passing a dummy input to completedJobs

```
function j = completedJobs(varargin)
    persistent n
    if isempty(n)
        n = 0;
    end
    if numel(varargin) ~=0
    else
    n = n+1;
    end
    j=n;
end
```